# Flutter: how do I give to colored container opacity?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

why can't I assign opacity to the color in this container?

this works:

```
class ColouredContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)=>
    Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(color: greens[1]),);
}
```

this return the error below:

```
class ColouredContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)=>
    Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(color: greens[1]
      .withOpacity(50) /// <= THIS!
    ),
  );
}
```

> I/flutter (18323): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
>   I/flutter (18323): The following assertion was thrown building BackGround(dirty):
>   I/flutter (18323): 'dart:ui/painting.dart': Failed assertion: line 188: '': is not true.
>   I/flutter (18323):
>   I/flutter (18323): Either the assertion indicates an error in the framework itself, or we should provide substantially
>   I/flutter (18323): more information in this error message to help you determine and fix the underlying cause.
>   I/flutter (18323): In either case, please report this assertion by filing a bug on GitHub:
>   I/flutter (18323):   https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/new?template=BUG.md

ultimately: how do I give to colored container opacity?

thanks for the help

Comment: What is 'greens'?

Comment: Try Colors.green[500]

Comment: greens are  top level const List<Color> greens = [...]; it's not the color, otherwise wouldn't work even without opacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check the source code, the `line 188 from painting.dart`:

```
  Color withOpacity(double opacity) {
    assert(opacity >= 0.0 && opacity <= 1.0);
    return withAlpha((255.0 * opacity).round());
  }
```

According to `assert` function, you must enter some value between 0.0 & 1.0 inclusive. That's the error. So the answer:

```
class ColouredContainer extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)=>
    Container( decoration: BoxDecoration(color: greens[1]
      .withOpacity(0.5)
    ),
  );
}
```